# How to get a string without "" in json response

Tags: json, spring-boot, jersey

I am new to springboot, i am getting a response as below in my json response:

`"Number": "08002050"`

I have defined it as String in my spring boot app.

I want to get a response as below:

`"Number": 08002050`

How do i accomplish this. please help

Comment: In fact you want to parse your string as an integer right?

Comment: You must parse String to int in server side.

Comment: To parse a string into an integer in java use `Integer.parseInt("08002050")`

Comment: This cannot happen right as the field here "Number" is a string and cant accept Integer.parseInt("08002050") as its input to Number filed in setter method!!

Comment: @Afsun What do you mean when you say server side exactly here?

Comment: I have just add as an answer my opinion.

Comment: Please suggest any solution with 0 suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it in server side with a tricky way.

```
public class User {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore  // ignore this field when serialize
    private String number;

    @JsonProperty(value = "number") // change name of field when serialize
    private int intValueOfNumber;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getIntValueOfNumber() {
        return Integer.parseInt(number); // parse number string to int
    }

    public void setIntValueOfNumber(int intValueOfNumber) {
        this.intValueOfNumber = intValueOfNumber;
    }


}
```

In this entity `@JsonIgnore` annotation is ignore your field for `JSON` serialization and pass `intValueOfNumber` as int to JSON. Your json will be following:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Java","number":44124}
```

You may lost zero suffix of number string when you parse it to int.

Comment: I need it to appear exactly same actually as "Number": 08002050 with 0 suffix. If we have to achieve something like "Number": 8002050 with out : suffix then there is a easy way just to add one new annotation as `@JsonRawValue` for the respective string field. So please suggest some other option where i can get 0 suffix as well

Comment: I have no any other idea.